# Marmelade Juice: error: SDK "macosx10.10" cannot be located

Tags: android, ios

I am very new to Marmelade. I have tried to convert my iOS game to android with this tool, and have fixed a few errors. This one I am unable to understand. Could anybody guide me? I am running OS X 10.10 (14A343f), and the game is build with Xcode 6 GM. I am sure this is just an error caused by the new OS, but it would be nice to get it working.

Here is the relevant log:

Executing: '/usr/bin/xcodebuild -project TallyBoard.xcodeproj -configuration Debug -sdk macosx10.10' xcodebuild: error: SDK "macosx10.10" cannot be located. error: Executing '/usr/bin/xcodebuild -project TallyBoard.xcodeproj -configuration Debug -sdk macosx10.10' failed. (return code 64) FAILED (error code=3)

Comment: All you have to do is install the Yosemite Xcode 6.1 beta. https://developer.apple.com/xcode/downloads/ That gives you the 10.10 sdk.

Comment: the odd thing is, it worked with any version except for the GM. I double-checked this with Marmalade support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After feedback from Marmalade support, this was an issue with the GM-release of Xcode beta 6.